# Can't see all my edits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, edit-history

I am sure that I edited the following answer

[How may we prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh^2(x)-x\over \cosh^3(x)}\cdot{4x\over e^x}\mathrm dx=2-\zeta(2)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220652/how-may-we-prove-that-int-0-infty-sinh2x-x-over-cosh3x-cdot4x-o/2223127#2223127)

at least three times but in the editing history

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2223127/revisions

It says that I only edited only once. Actually before the the last edit the (edited) link disappeared.

I had answers where the editing shows more than one edit. Am I amissing something or it doesn't show small edits ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does not seem like a bug. Edits done withing five minutes by the same user after posting or an initial edit are put together in one revision to avoid cluttering the revision history.

(Except if somebody comments on a post in the interim. Then a new revision is created to avoid confusion over comments that refer to a part of the post that then gets changed.)